# CURL missing data from write function

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am using the *CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION* CURL option to get website contents, along with the *CURLOPT_WRITEDATA* option to specify my buffer. According to the documentation when using C++, I must define a static class member function with the following signature for the write callback, otherwise, I will get a segmentation fault:

```
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
```

I know that, according to the documentation, that the maximum write size is defined in *CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE*. But when I am simply printing the contents of *ptr*, I get less content that specified in *CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE*. That is, I get roughly 1/3 of the website contents.

When I don't add this *CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION* option, CURL will by default use *fwrite()* to *stdout* to print the write data, where I can see all the contents of the webpage.

I am therefore asking; why is it, that I can't get the entire write data from the web page?

Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class curl_write
{
public:
    static size_t write_data(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* buffer)
    {
        ((std::string*) buffer)->append((char*) ptr, nmemb);
        return nmemb;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string buffer;

    CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ensk.dict.cc/");
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 
    curl_write::write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);

    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the end of the expected output:

```
<br>
<div class="hl3" style="margin:25px 0px 3px 4px;">News &amp; History (<a href="//www.dict.cc/news_en.rss.php" style="color:#36c">RSS</a>)</div>
</div><div style="width:728px; padding:0px 1px">
<div class="news"><em>2020-08-11:</em> Keyboard handling improved for the <a href="https://m.dict.cc/">mobile dict.cc website</a> when used on a PC/Mac. Just type your keyword, regardless of where the cursor is. Pressing the Tab key (followed by Enter) selects from the suggestions in most browsers.</div>
<div class="news"><em>2020-07-07:</em> The new vocabulary trainer (only web, not yet in the app) now displays a message if there are several possible answers. The message can be clicked to show the translations currently not being asked for. The trainer now also accepts any of the other answers and moves the corresponding card to the next box, but it will keep asking for the missing answer. To get help finding out which term is asked for, it's still possible to press the space bar for the next correct character.</div>
<div class="news"><em>2020-06-29:</em> The mobile website now offers audio buttons for both languages, saving the additional click on terms for re-translation.</div>
<div class="news"><em>2020-03-30:</em> The new vocabulary trainer is now officially released! The old version stays available for the time being and can be used via the "v1" or "old" links and menu items.</div>
<div class="news">» <a href="//www.dict.cc/german-english-dictionary.php"><b>English: News History</b></a><br>
» <a href="//www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch-woerterbuch.php"><b>Deutsch: Verlauf der Mitteilungen</b></a></div>
</div><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="728" style="margin-left:1px;height:22px"> 
        <tbody><tr><td class="td1"><a href="#top" name="bottom" style="color:white;">back to top</a> | <a href="https://ensk.dict.cc/" style="color:white;">home</a></td><td class="td1" align="right">© 2002 - 2020 <a href="https://www.hemetsberger.com" style="color:white;">Paul Hemetsberger</a> | <a href="//www.dict.cc/?s=about%3A#impressum" style="color:white;">contact / privacy</a></td></tr></tbody></table><img src="https://www4.dict.cc/img/hr4.gif" width="728" height="4" alt="" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 1px"><div class="aftertable">Slovak-English online dictionary (Anglicko-slovenský slovník) developed to help you share your knowledge with others. <a href="//www.dict.cc/?s=about%3A">More information</a><br>Links to this dictionary or to single translations are very welcome! <a href="//www.dict.cc/?s=about%3Afaq">Questions and Answers</a></div><script type="text/javascript">add_inputhasfocus_changer();</script><script type="text/javascript">var my_vocab_lists = [];
</script><div id="speechlayer" style="width:1px;height:1px"></div><div id="recthomebot" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="text-align:center;width:300px"><span class="noline" style="font-size:10px;color:#999">Advertisement</span></div><!-- 
headerbidding part2
--><div id="snhb-detail_rectangle-0"></div><script type="text/javascript"> snhb.queue.push( function(){ snhb.startAuction(['detail_rectangle']); }); </script></div><script type="text/javascript">
            if (document.getElementById("recthome")) {
            document.getElementById("recthomebot").style.position="absolute";
            document.getElementById("recthomebot").style.left=getX(document.getElementById("recthome"))+"px";
            document.getElementById("recthomebot").style.top=getY(document.getElementById("recthome"))+"px";
            }
            </script></div><iframe name="__tcfapiLocator" style="display: none;"></iframe><iframe name="__uspapiLocator" style="display: none;"></iframe><iframe name="__cmpLocator" style="display: none;"></iframe></body></html>
```

The difference from the actual output is that the last 6.5 lines are missing.

SOLUTION

The solution was to exchange the carriage return characters with the space character.

Comment: Are you comparing it with view-source in the browser? The last few lines for "Advertisement" are likely added dynamically after the page loads, they're not part of the initial http transfer.

Comment: I do receive the "Advertisement" part.

Answer (score 0):

`*((std::string*) buffer) += (char*) ptr` will only work if `ptr` is both null terminated and contains no nulls. The latter depends on what you're downloading and curl [explicitly states](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) the former is not true.

You should use [`std::string::append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) instead:

```
((std::string*) buffer)->append(ptr, nmemb);
```

As the documentation states:

> Your callback should return the number of bytes actually taken care of. If that amount differs from the amount passed to your callback function, it'll signal an error condition to the library. This will cause the transfer to get aborted

```
return nmemb + 1;
```

should be

```
return nmemb;
```

otherwise the transfer will be aborted.

Comment: I did this, but still the same problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I provided the minimal reproducible example and changed the return value. I got close to the write data, but still not everything.

Comment: Are you expecting all the data in a single callback? CURL provides no such guarantee

Comment: As I wrote, I know there is a limit, but I couldn't find a way to get all the data, even though it required multiple callbacks.

Comment: A full example showing the expected and actual output would be helpful

Comment: I gave an example of the last bit of the output, since I am not allowed to post that many characters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be getting the data through multiple callbacks and std::string does not need to be explicitely null-terminated. So like this:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class curl_write
{
public:
    static size_t write_data(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* buffer)
    {
        ((std::string*) buffer)->append((char*) ptr, nmemb);

        return nmemb;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string buffer;

    CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ensk.dict.cc/");
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 
    curl_write::write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);
    curl_easy_perform(handle);
    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't change anything. The result is still the same.

Comment: `curl https://ensk.dict.cc/ > cmdline.txt; ./a.out > cprog.txt; ls -l` gives me cmdline.txt at 34751 bytes, cprog.txt at 34753 bytes because of the extra newline. The page downloaded exactly as it would with the command-line utility.

Comment: @MartinPekár what result do you see?

Comment: I see the exact same thing, which of course is good. But when I am printing it in the program, I am missing the last bit.

Comment: does this help?: `for (auto &a:buffer) if (a==13) a=20;
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;`

Comment: (the data contains CR characters, which will move the cursor to the beginning of the line and overwrite stuff when printing on *nix)

Comment: I get the full write data now. But now there are unrecognized characters different places in the data.

Comment: not meant as a solution, just demonstrating that the data is there, the problem is with printing it out.

Comment: Then I can confirm. The data is there.

Comment: Wait, why did I put 20? That was of course supposed to be space (0x20 or 32), so that's where the invalid characters came from. I need more coffee. :)